# How do I fill a form with characters that have diacritics?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, casperjs, diacritics

I try to fill a form with German mutated vowels (ä ö ü), but they don't get accepted.
Tried to escape or replace them with the html equivalent, no success either.

```
this.fillSelectors('form[name="address"]', {
        'div input[name="adrStreet"]':          'Einöde',
        'div input[name="adrCity"]':            'Pfaffstätten',
    }, true);
```

converts to 
**Ein܀de**
- and -
**Pfaffst܀tten**
in the form.

The system itself is Debian with locale set to `LANG=de_AT.UTF-8`
Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Does the font you're using to display the results support those characters?

Comment: Are you sure that your editor handles those characters correctly and the script uses actually UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Great tip, you got it. Editor encoding had been wrong. Many thanks!